# Apache cxf - jaxrs client spring configuration ( Injecting proxies )

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, jax-rs, cxf

I am consuming REST webservice using (**Example**) URL like:

`http://www.restsampleservice.com/api?username=tom&password=jerry`

The ws at this url returns the user securedcode.

**Goal:**

I want to integrate this Rest ws to my Spring web app. So *how my JaxRS client serviceclass and the address should be in context xml?*

Please find my assumption below:

```
<jaxrs:client id="restClient"
       address=" http://www.restsampleservice.com/api?username=tom&password=jerry"
       serviceClass=?
       inheritHeaders="true">
       <jaxrs:headers>
           <entry key="Accept" value="text/plain"/>
       </jaxrs:headers>
</jaxrs:client>
```

Comment: Try to re-consider your design. Sending username and password as query parameters not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a proxy class like this

```
public interface RestClient{

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public String getUserSecureCode( @QueryParam("username") String username ,@QueryParam("password") String password)
}
```

The spring file looks like this

```
<jaxrs:client id="restClient"
   address="http://www.restsampleservice.com/api"
   serviceClass="test.RestClient"
   inheritHeaders="true">
   <jaxrs:headers>
       <entry key="Accept" value="text/plain"/>
   </jaxrs:headers>
</jaxrs:client>
```

You can use also the interface in server side

```
public class RestClientImpl implements RestClient{
    public String getUserSecureCode( String username , String password){
        //doSomething...
        return userSecureCode
    }
}
```